# Error when parsing a date from a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, datetime

I have an MVC application that has this url

```
http://localhost:10003/Agromilieu2/Beheer/Teksten/Teksten/AMI2WUI?vanTime=04/08/2014%2015:00:00
```

from which I must read vanTime.

I'm using this

```
var vanTime = $.urlParam('vanTime');
var sDate = new Date(Date.parse(vanTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));


$.urlParam = function (name) {
                var results = new RegExp('[\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);

                if (results != null)
                    return results[1];
            }
```

But I keep getting a Invalid Date error.

Comment: What are you getting as a result from calling it? What is `sDate`? What is `vanTime` before you try to create a date? Also, since your date/time is in a recognizable format you can just do `new Date(vanTime)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before extracting `vanTime`, make sure to decode your url string like this:

```
decodeURI('http://localhost:10003/Agromilieu2/Beheer/Teksten/Teksten/AMI2WUI?vanTime=04/08/2014%2015:00:00');
```

The problem is, that the space in the date is encoded as `%20`. I guess this causes the error.

Comment: That's all it took. Tks.